# How to select all rows in table view by pressing button in js

Tags: javascript

i am using titanium mobile studio to create some application,

i have table view and i need to select all rows when i press (select all) button.

i know there is `hascheck` properties but i didnt find the way to select all row.

```
var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({
                data : Call.makeTable(),
                width:300,
                height:250,
                top:120,
                borderColor:'orange',
                borderWidth:1,
                borderRadius:10,
                });

tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        var index = e.index;
        var section = e.section;
        var row = e.row;
        var rowdata = e.rowData;

        if(row.hasCheck === true) {
            row.setHasCheck(false);
            Ti.API.info("unchecked");
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(index == arr[i][0]){
                     arr.splice(i, 1);

                 }

             }

        }

        else {
            row.setHasCheck(true);
            Ti.API.info("checked");
            var Person=Call.CreateObject(rowdata);
            arr.push([index,Person]);


        }

        Ti.API.info("click");
        Ti.API.info(row.hasCheck);
        Ti.API.info(index);
        Ti.API.info(section);
        Ti.API.info(rowdata.person.fullName);
        Ti.API.info(rowdata.person.phone);
        Ti.API.info(rowdata.person.email);

});
```

and this is the button.

```
SelectAll.addEventListener('click', function(){

    //here the code
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you :

```
for(var i =0;i<tableview.data.length;i++){
    var rows = tableview.data[i].rows;
    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; ++j) {
        rows[j].setHasCheck(true);

    }
}
```